# In vim, how to detach/open an exist window to a new tab?

Tags: vim

For example:

I'm editing a file, and I use command-line mode (:help) to open help file
but this help file is be opened in the some tab with my file
so, I want to open/detach this help window to a new tab

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131393/remapping-help-in-vim-to-open-in-a-new-tab - Your question was already answered 3 times on stackoverflow. I think you will find more answers about this subject there :)

Comment: yes, it really helps, thanks, and there a slit difference, I want open the exist window content to a new tab.

Comment: @nwildner lovespring, could one of you please post the solution from SO as an answer here? Or, if not, please delete the question. Otherwise it will just stay here, unanswered.

Comment: @lovespring - WHY do you want to open help on your current window and AFTER THAT move to a new tab, when you can directly open it already on another tab? Deeply in your heart you need to operate this way? `:tab help` should be enough...

Comment: @nwildner No, I type "help", it already opened in the exist tab and with a new window.  And also, I use netrw to explore files, when I middle click left mouse on the file, the file also open in the exist window, not in a new tab. I used to edit file in a new tab.

Comment: Well, take a look at my answer, specially about the keyboard shortcut "Control + W" - "Shift + T".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want REALLY want this, you should use one of these after enter `:help` :

```
:tab split
```

Or

```
:tabedit %
```

And this will make a new copy of the current page(help) be positioned on a new tab. If you want to move,  hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> (release) <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> will do the trick. I think that this key combination is what you really want.

If you want to be proactive and open your help on a new tab, `:tab help` will be enough

**Related Stuff:**

- [How do I move an existing window to a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758301/how-do-i-move-an-existing-window-to-a-new-tab)
- [How to edit the same file in multiple tabs in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317287/how-to-edit-the-same-file-in-multiple-tabs-in-vim)
- [Remapping :help in Vim to open in a new tab [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131393/remapping-help-in-vim-to-open-in-a-new-tab)

Comment: :tabedit %  means edit the current window (then the buffer which this window belongs to) in a new tab. this is what i want ! thinak you.

Comment: How to close the prev window, and "open new"+ "close the prev" = detach.